# AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'suggest'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nltk

i want to do a project of word spelling correction in somali language using nltk.corpus.udhr.fileids() package but the problem is that the attrbutes of nltk does not support this language and it's difficult to me to train my own spelling correction since i am new in machine learning.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('udhr')
from nltk.corpus import udhr
nltk.corpus.udhr.fileids()
somali_text = nltk.corpus.udhr.raw('Somali-Latin1')
len(somali_text)
words = list(somali_text)
print(words)
#dictionary that maps each word to its frequency

frequence_dict = {}
for word in words:
  if word not in frequence_dict:
    frequence_dict[word] = 1
  else:
    frequence_dict[word] += 1

#sorting the dictionary by frequency

sorted_frequency_dict = sorted(frequence_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

#misspelled words
misspelled_words = []
for word, frequency in sorted_frequency_dict:
  if frequency < 3:
    misspelled_words.append(word)
  
#corrections for misspelled words

corrections = {}
for misspelled_word in misspelled_words:
  corrections[misspelled_word] = nltk.suggest(misspelled_word)
```

when i run the code it dispalys the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-0f8ec385447f> in <cell line: 25>()
     24 corrections = {}
     25 for misspelled_word in misspelled_words:
---> 26   corrections[misspelled_word] = nltk.suggest(misspelled_word)
     27 
     28 # Suggest corrections for the misspelled words

AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'suggest'.
```

Comment: Could you share the link to the documentation part of nltk where there is 'suggest' attribute described?